# How to disable serializing interface properties in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have an interface which contains properties of type `ICommand`. When I serialize my concrete class instances that implement this interface, the `ICommand` properties are also serialized:

```
public interface IMyInterface : ICloneable, IEditableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ICommand CmdMainDbBrowseButtonClicked { get; }
    ICommand CmdAnalyticsDbBrowseButtonClicked { get; }
    ICommand CmdMediaDbBrowseButtonClicked { get; }
    ICommand CmdWebTrakDbBrowseButtonClicked { get; }
    ICommand CmdTestButtonClicked { get; }
}
```

JSON serialized form:

```
[
  {
    "CmdMainDbBrowseButtonClicked": {},
    "CmdAnalyticsDbBrowseButtonClicked": {},
    "CmdMediaDbBrowseButtonClicked": {},
    "CmdWebTrakDbBrowseButtonClicked": {},
    "CmdTestButtonClicked": {},
    ...
   }
]
```

This presents a problem when deserializing, as the deserializer does not know the concrete type of `ICommand` is `RelayCommand`.

How can I completely disable the serialization of the `ICommand` properties, or coerce their types to `RelayCommand` at deserialization time?

Comment: Not a duplicate. That other topic refers to the .NET BCL. I'm referring specifically to JSON.NET http://james.newtonking.com/json

Comment: You can selectively ignore properties across classes using a custom contract resolver.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18548894/10263) for an example of that approach.  On deserialization, you can use a custom JsonConverter to coerce an interface or abstract class to the correct concrete type using other info in the JSON to indicate which type to create.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19308474/10263) explains how to do that.

Comment: You could add `[JsonIgnore]` to each property.

Comment: `[JsonIgnore]` is what I needed, thanks.