# Serialize and ignore properties which throw an exception

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Say I have a class:

```
public class Cat
{
    public int Hunger {get; set;}
    public int Sleepiness {get; set;}
    public int Usefullness {
      get { throw new DivideByZeroException(); }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to serialize it as below:

```
public ActionResult GetMyCat()
{
     Cat c = new Cat()
    {
        Hunger = 10,
        Sleepiness = 10
    };

    return Json(c);
}
```

I can't modify the "Cat" class. Can I have the MVC JSON Serializer ignore the error that one property threw, (if it threw an error) and just give me an empty/default value for that property?

Comment: Do you *have* to use the built-in JSON serializer?

Comment: The problem is, I'm dealing with HUGE poco classes with hundreds of properties. I wouldn't say **have**, but I'd rather not write a serializer for these classes unless it's dynamic.

Comment: is it possible to add an attribute to you property? 
if so you may try, `[JsonIgnore]`

Comment: No, but there are other serializers out there that do a better job, like JSON.NET, and can handle this kind of situation. No need to write your own.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543482/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-get-only-properties-in-json-net-without-using-jsonignor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create class extension that will return proper object

```
public static class CatExtensions
 {
        public static object GetObject(this Cat value)
        {
            return new
            {
                Hunger = value.Hunger,
                Sleepiness = value.Sleepiness
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any way I can do this dynamically?

Comment: Actually, you just gave me an idea. I think I know how I can do this dynamically. I'll give it a shot. It's going to be ugly though.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamically? Please share what you have in mind :)

Comment: Say the cat class had five million properties and you were too lazy to write a huge GetObject() function :P I'm thinking about going through the properties by reflection.

Comment: @David, It's going to get tricky when you get to your "dynamic exclusion" logic. How would you determine which properties stay and which should be left out of the new object? Personal opinion, if you go with the "new object approach", rather take the shot and create them manually as in nomail's example, this gives you control in the long run IMHO :)

Comment: do you really need all those five million properties? I mean returning 5mil properties to client doesn't seem very user-friendly

Comment: Haha, just kidding about that. And about the tricky part, see my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, This is ugly, but here is one way:

```
Cat c = new Cat()
{
    Hunger = 10,
    Sleepiness = 10
};

dynamic dynamicCat = new ExpandoObject();
IDictionary<string, object> dynamicCatExpando = dynamicCat;

Type type = c.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    try
    {
        dynamicCatExpando.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(c, null));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       //Or just don't add the property here. Your call.
        object defaultValue = type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null;
        dynamicCatExpando.Add(property.Name, defaultValue); //I still need to figure out how to get the default value if it's a primitive type.
    }
}

return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dynamicCatExpando), "application/Json");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an external JSON serialization library such as [this one](https://lbv.github.io/litjson/) and add a custom attribute to skip the value. Or perhaps add a try catch around getting the value and ignoring it when the trap is sprung.

Comment: Did you miss the `I can't modify the Cat class` part?

Comment: Sorry, i did. Though you could perhaps still add a `try catch` around getting the value and just continue along if it fails.

Comment: When retrieve of any member fails serialization as a process will fail also, you cannot simply continue working.

Comment: You could customize/create your own JSON serializer that on an exception in a member skips it and continues processing at the next one.