# How to omit get-only properties only when [JsonProperty] attribute is not set on it?

Tags: c#, json.net

I use Json.Net in my project.
I need to find a solution where get-only properties do not serialize only if attribute `[JsonProperty]` is not set.

```
public class Example
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string ThisPropertyHasToBeSerialized {get;}

    public string ThisPropertyHasToBeSkipped {get;}
}
```

I found a partial answer to it at:
[Is there a way to ignore get-only properties in Json.NET without using JsonIgnore attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543482/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-get-only-properties-in-json-net-without-using-jsonignor)
But I want to leave an opportunity for get-only properties to be serialized in case it is needed.
I am thinking of implementing it in CreateProperty function like this

```
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public static readonly CustomContractResolver Instance = new CustomContractResolver();

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if(property.Writable||????????????)return property;
        else ?????  
    }
}
```

Is there a way to check if json Attribute was set on a property (`[JsonProperty]`) but not `[JsonIgnore]`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your resolver like this:

```
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public static readonly CustomContractResolver Instance = new CustomContractResolver();

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        // Ignore get-only properties that do not have a [JsonProperty] attribute
        if (!property.Writable && member.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>() == null)
            property.Ignored = true;

        return property;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4oi04N

Comment: Wonderful. That's what I needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem.  Glad I could help.